# Xlsx file corupted when downloading

Tags: java, unix, download, apache-camel, apache-poi

I created an xlsx file using XSSF from apache-poi and creating a route which returns this file using apache-camel. 
The file is created ok, I made all the possible content settings that I found, download is working without any problems on my local machine (windows).
After deploying it to a Unix server (under Tomcat7) and accesing the http path from that server, the file is downloaded but it is corrupted, excel will not open it. I receive the following errors:

> "Excel found unreadable content in 'Filename.xlsx'. Do you want to recover the contents of this workbook? If you trust the source of this workbook, click Yes." After I click yes follow up error shows: 
>   "Excel cannot open the file 'Filename.xlsx' because the file format or file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file."

I am using a processor called from camel to create the Workbook file, and create all the content settings in the processor, this should not be a problem, I logged them outside the processor and all is set. Also everything is working as it should, but only on local PC. 
Note: I have the same version of Java/apache-camel/poi/tomcat and so on.. like the server.

Some code snippet:

```
    XSSFWorkbook xlsx = writeToExcel(list);

    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = getByteFormat(exchange, xlsx);

    exchange.getIn().setHeader("Content-Disposition",
            "attachment; filename=ProductExports.xlsx");
    exchange.getIn().setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE,"application/vnd.openxml");
    exchange.getIn().setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_LENGTH,bos.toByteArray().length);
    exchange.getIn().setHeader("Expires","0");
    exchange.getIn().setBody(bos.toByteArray());
```

The getByteFormat() part:

```
    private ByteArrayOutputStream getByteFormat(Exchange exchange,
        XSSFWorkbook xlsx) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
        xlsx.write(bos);
    } finally {
        bos.close();
    }
    return bos;
}
```

I searched around but didn't find any examples with camel-poi, where people encountered the same problems.
Note: I tried also with HSSF format, and with different CONTENT_TYPE settings, the result is the same.

I guess maybe the problem is caused cause I pass the byte array and somehow Unix systems are interpreting this in a different way, or maybe something with file transfer partitioning. The corrupted file has a bigger dimension then the one which is created normally, probably contains some extra lines, not sure if this matters.

Comment: Did you check the one from the unix server is the same length as the windows one, not zero bytes etc? You could also run a binary diff on the two files (the one you download from Windows, and the one you download from a Unix server), which might help narrow down the issue.

Comment: Could you please try with "application/vnd.ms-excel" as ContentType

Comment: I comapred the length (windows:  4560 vs  4582 unix). Also compared the files in notepad ++ and the corrupted file contains all the information from the good file, and some more stuff, which i guess is generated by unix/download browser.. etc.. no ideea

Comment: I suggest the problem is in the `getByteFormat()` method, but until you post it the entire question is a complete waste of time and space.

Comment: I will edit it with the method.

Comment: Sounds to me like you're sending it back as text not binary. I don't know Camel, but is there perhaps a different response method / setting needed to force it to binary mode?

Comment: Looks like you are clsing bos in getByteFormat() method and again the same object you are trying to add  here exchange.getIn().setBody(bos.toByteArray());. Hence, can you please close the stream after setting into body.

Comment: Do not close in getByteFormat() and close after setting into body.

Comment: @Subbu - I moved the closing of the stream after inserting in the body, the same output. Also keep in mind that this exact same code is working from locally with Windows OS.

Comment: @Gagravarr - If i print the body it is in a wierd text format, I will try to find out how can I force it to byteArray.. but still, why it is working then in windows. Ex:CN���d�s��{�9W��|k����͜��V��̹[]��s21�R��wL͜��A�_:8{��A�
�3�Vj���eQCK�Ƿ�4Sq���ڗ[��5�j?�8�[B�3�J:���Y�ޝO}5��=�招�� o��*hL�劬�?�R\7D�ɬ� `���!^lL�\P� ]< ��v���0����6�%L7),v�.��R�pgr��Ѣ��X�W&y����Qt�>q��S[~?��r`�Q��x��p`� 2�"/�_s!@n9+� %��:l�E-/A0��m�@���Ʋ24� 8�����֤��P�cU���a��Be�
/=�+�*`�4�v暨ZP�� ,g�A�����CK�(W��D��ua�������(N�~�C�Dq4�

Answer (score 0):

Below the code working fine in Windows and Unix. Hope this will may help you.

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
              OutputStream outStream = null;
              try {
                   response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
                   response.setHeader
                     ("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Sample.xlsx");

                   outStream = response.getOutputStream();
                   Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
                   XSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet(sheetName) ;

                //iterating r number of rows
                for (int r=0;r < 5; r++ )
                {
                    XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(r);

                    //iterating c number of columns
                    for (int c=0;c < 5; c++ )
                    {
                        XSSFCell cell = row.createCell(c);

                        cell.setCellValue("Cell "+r+" "+c);
                    }
                }
                wb.write(outStream);
                outStream.close();
            } 
              catch (Exception e){
               throw new ServletException("Exception in Excel Sample Servlet", e);
              } 
              finally{
               if (outStream != null)
                   outStream.close();
              }
    }
```

Comment: This is basically the same thing as my code, but instead the logic beeing done in a Camel Proccessor, this is done with a servlet, which means instead of exchange, i will have the outstream from the response, other then that the content parts are set the same. Unfortunatelly I cannot use servlets for my implementation, nor I want to use, since I want to use camel for this. What I want to say is that the common part is similar (where you set the content type and disposition). So I don`t see what changes should I take in my code from here. Anyhow, thanks for the answer.